# Help trying to invent a tactical chess opening

Tags: opening, beginner

I need help!

I am trying to invent something out of my own imagination. But something isn't right... I am playing as white and I can't figure out why is it that I have the feeling about losing a pawn on c3?

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 Nf6
2. g3 g6
3. Bg2 Bg7
4. O-O O-O
5. c3 Nc6
6. b3 d5
7. d4 Bf5
8. Be3 Ne4
9. Nh4 Qd7
```

Any suggestions and opinions will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be good for us to know what your intent of this opening is. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the point of 5.c3? You already control square d4, it blocks a possible square of the knight and doesn't help with development.

Comment: And if you're going to play b3 (usually with the intention of playing Bb2, right?) then c3 blocks that path of the bishop. And if you're not playing Bb2, why weaken your position (especially the long diagonal) with b3?

Answer (score 1):

The Be3 would make more sense on b2 since that would not only support c3 and d4, but also make room for opening the centre via e4 later (after Rf1-e1). Placing a bishop on the 3rd rank in the centre with the pawn behind still on the 2nd rank tends to become awkward.

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of losing c3, you shouldn't play b3 in the first place (unless you intend to [fianchetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fianchetto) the bishop, as [@Ras](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/15250/7297) mentions). Black also doesn't threaten to occupy c4 (or a4) with a piece. Remember that pawns cannot move backwards, so every time you move a pawn you lose control over the squares you leave behind.

Also, if you're trying to play/invent tactical openings, you're better off starting with 1. e4. The open positions which arise from these opening offer more chance for tactics.